# Flot charts - How to plot only 1 tick per month on x-axis?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I want to have 1 tick on the x-axis every month.
I have this setting in flot charts, but it sometimes only plots 1 tick in the x-axis every 2 months

```
var options = {
        xaxis: { mode: "time", timeformat: "%m/%d/%y", minTickSize: [1, "month"] }
    };
```

Comment: Please provide  some sample data which replicates your problem.   if you only have a data point per month it might be simpler to use a category axes.

Answer (score 2):

If you want full control over the ticks on an axis you can set the `ticks` property with an array, for example:

```
var tickArray = [ new Date(2013, 0, 1).getTime(), new Date(2013, 1, 1).getTime(), ... ];
var options = {
    xaxis: { mode: "time", timeformat: "%m/%d/%y", ticks: tickArray }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tickSize` property to set 1 month on x-axis like this.

```
tickSize: [1, "month"]
```